# What does 'URI has an authority component' mean?

Tags: java, glassfish

I am attempting to build a Java web project on NetBeans 6.8, but I get get the following error:

> The module has not been deployed.

It points to my `build-impl.xml` file, line 577:

```
<nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
```

The GlassFish v3 error log says:

```
SEVERE: Exception in command execution : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component
  at java.io.File.<init>(File.java:368)`..., etc.
```

What does *"URI has an authority component"* mean?

Comment: Did you mean to tag this with "j2ee"?

Comment: I looked up 'URI syntax authority component' and this looks like a good reference: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2396.txt...

Comment: do you think it has anything to do with the fact taht my netbeans workspace is over a unc connected path?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The solution was simply that the URI was malformed (because the location of my project was over a "\\" UNC path).  This issue was fixed when I used a local workspace.

Comment: Can you send me the complete stacktrace from the server log?  It seems like there needs to be a code fix here... or a better error message.

Comment: let me know where to send it? or post it in a comment?

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't resolve anything for me.  Everything is running off of my local machine already.

Answer (score 42):

An authority is a portion of a URI.  Your error suggests that it was not expecting one.  The authority section is shown below, it is what is known as the website part of the url.

From RFC3986 on [URIs](https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt):

> The following is an example URI and its component parts:

```
     foo://example.com:8042/over/there?name=ferret#nose
     \_/   \______________/\_________/ \_________/ \__/
      |           |            |            |        |
   scheme     authority       path        query   fragment
      |   _____________________|__
     / \ /                        \
     urn:example:animal:ferret:nose
```

So there are two formats, one with an authority and one not.    Regarding slashes:

> "When authority is not present, the path cannot begin with two slash
> characters ("//")."

Source: https://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt  (search for text '*authority is not present, the path cannot begin with two slash*')

Answer (score 2):

Flip over to the GlassFish output tab, it'll give you better info.  Netbeans gives you that generic error, but Glassfish gives you the details.  When I get this it's usually a typo in one of my JSP or XML files...

Comment: i posted the glassfish error above. i've double checked my typos and syntax.  still not sure.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (NetBeans 6.9.1) and the fix is so simple :)

I realized NetBeans didn't create a META-INF folder and thus no `context.xml` was found, so I create the META-INF folder under the main project folder and create file `context.xml` with the following content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/home"/>
```

And it runs :)

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the URL of the application conflicted with a module in the Sun GlassFish.
So, in the file `sun-web.xml` I renamed the <context-root>/servlets-samples</context-root>.

It is now working.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced similar problem while working on Affable Bean e-commerce site development. I received an error:

> Module has not been deployed.

I checked the `sun-resources.xml` file and found the following statements which resulted in the error.

```
<resources>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true"
                   jndi-name="jdbc/affablebean"
                   object-type="user"
                   pool-name="AffableBeanPool">
    </jdbc-resource>

    <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false"
                          associate-with-thread="false"
                          connection-creation-retry-attempts="0"
                          connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10"
                          connection-leak-reclaim="false"
                          connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0"
                          connection-validation-method="auto-commit"
                          datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource"
                          fail-all-connections="false"
                          idle-timeout-in-seconds="300"
                          is-connection-validation-required="false"
                          is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true"
                          lazy-connection-association="false"
                          lazy-connection-enlistment="false"
                          match-connections="false"
                          max-connection-usage-count="0"
                          max-pool-size="32"
                          max-wait-time-in-millis="60000"
                          name="AffableBeanPool"
                          non-transactional-connections="false"
                          pool-resize-quantity="2"
                          res-type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource"
                          statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1"
                          steady-pool-size="8"
                          validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0"
                          wrap-jdbc-objects="false">

        <description>Connects to the affablebean database</description>
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/affablebean"/>
        <property name="User" value="root"/>
        <property name="Password" value="nbuser"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
</resources>
```

Then I changed the statements to the following which is simple and works. I was able to run the file successfully.

```
<resources>
    <jdbc-resource enabled="true" jndi-name="jdbc/affablebean" object-type="user" pool-name="AffablebeanPool">
        <description/>
    </jdbc-resource>
    <jdbc-connection-pool allow-non-component-callers="false" associate-with-thread="false" connection-creation-retry-attempts="0" connection-creation-retry-interval-in-seconds="10" connection-leak-reclaim="false" connection-leak-timeout-in-seconds="0" connection-validation-method="auto-commit" datasource-classname="com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlDataSource" fail-all-connections="false" idle-timeout-in-seconds="300" is-connection-validation-required="false" is-isolation-level-guaranteed="true" lazy-connection-association="false" lazy-connection-enlistment="false" match-connections="false" max-connection-usage-count="0" max-pool-size="32" max-wait-time-in-millis="60000" name="AffablebeanPool" non-transactional-connections="false" pool-resize-quantity="2" res-type="javax.sql.ConnectionPoolDataSource" statement-timeout-in-seconds="-1" steady-pool-size="8" validate-atmost-once-period-in-seconds="0" wrap-jdbc-objects="false">
        <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/AffableBean"/>
        <property name="User" value="root"/>
        <property name="Password" value="nbuser"/>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying a skeleton project called "jsf-blank", which did not demonstrate this problem with xhtml files; I concluded that there was an unknown problem in my project.  My solution may not have been too elegant, but it saved time.  I backed up the code and other files I'd already developed, deleted the project, and started over - recreated the project.  So far, I've added back most of the files and it looks pretty good.