# How to check MyEclipse VisualVM profiler for CODENAMEONE?

Tags: codenameone, profiler, myeclipse

I am unable to check codenameone app in profiler as it gives error as below.

[image]

Comment: It looks like a bug in my eclipse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366270/what-does-uri-has-an-authority-component-mean