# Maven error: URI has an authority component

Tags: maven, uri

I'm pretty new to maven and trying to build a code on Windows that works fine in linux.
I have 2 local repositories in my pom.xml:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>p2-repo-equinox_3.8.1</id>
        <layout>p2</layout>
        <url>file:///${basedir}/../xyz/abc/repository/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>p2-repo-common</id>
        <layout>p2</layout>
        <url>file:///${basedir}/../xyz/def/repository/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

When building, I get the error:

```
 Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to load p2 repository with ID 'p2-repo-equinox_3.8.1' from location file://D:/maven/myproject/../xyz/abc/repository/: URI has an authority component -> [Help 1]
```

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366270/what-does-uri-has-an-authority-component-mean), and tried adding a third slash to pass an empty authority component ( file:///) which made it work, but I'm not sure why the issue only happens in Windows in the first place and not on Linux.

Any Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this doesn't cause an error on linux is probably due to the difference in the value of **${basedir}** on the two platforms:

On Windows **${basedir}** will be set to something like **"c:/file/path"**

```
file://c:/file/path   <--- not happy
```

On linux **${basedir}** will be like **"/file/path"**

```
file:///file/path   <--- happy
```

Answer (score 0):

On a windows machine, the complete syntax is **file://host/path** .
If the host is your machine(localhost), it can be omitted, resulting in **file:///path** .

See [RFC 1738 – Uniform Resource Locators (URL)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt)

```
A file URL takes the form:

file://<host>/<path>
[…]

As a special case, <host> can be the string "localhost" or the empty string; this is interpreted as 'the machine from which the URL is being interpreted'.
```

Comment: Yes. He already fixed it with three slashes. I guess his question is, why is it that it works with 3 slashes as against 2 slashes on windows machine.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My question is, why doesn't this cause an issue on Linux?