# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component, Java web application not booting in eclipse neon

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

My eclipse got auto-upgraded from Mars to Neon. Since then, i am not able to start my java application from eclipse. This was working perfectly fine in Mars. Anybody know why? I am running on Windows

> Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI
>   has an authority component    at java.io.File.(File.java:423)   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.resource.impl.ResourceOracleImpl.createEntryForUrl(ResourceOracleImpl.java:164)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.resource.impl.ResourceOracleImpl.addAllClassPathEntries(ResourceOracleImpl.java:334)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.resource.impl.ResourceOracleImpl.getAllClassPathEntries(ResourceOracleImpl.java:358)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.resource.impl.ResourceOracleImpl.preload(ResourceOracleImpl.java:211)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.resource.impl.ResourceOracleImpl.preload(ResourceOracleImpl.java:202)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.resource.impl.ResourceOracleImpl.preload(ResourceOracleImpl.java:195)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode$1.run(DevMode.java:412)   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI has an authority component    at
>   java.io.File.(File.java:423)    at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.resource.impl.ResourceOracleImpl.createEntryForUrl(ResourceOracleImpl.java:164)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.resource.impl.ResourceOracleImpl.addAllClassPathEntries(ResourceOracleImpl.java:334)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.resource.impl.ResourceOracleImpl.getAllClassPathEntries(ResourceOracleImpl.java:358)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.resource.impl.ResourceOracleImpl.(ResourceOracleImpl.java:402)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDef.normalize(ModuleDef.java:545)   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:199)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromResources(ModuleDefLoader.java:169)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:141)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.loadModule(DevModeBase.java:1017)
>     at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.loadModule(DevMode.java:557)  at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartup(DevMode.java:443)    at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1083)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:836)  at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:311)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2366270/what-does-uri-has-an-authority-component-mean